# C# Windows Forms - Drag and Drop into an external web browser (Firefox)

Tags: c#, windows, forms, firefox, drag-and-drop

I have a Windows Form with a Label containing an URL. I want to drag this Label into Firefox and get a new tab opened with that URL. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

You must start a drag when the label is clicked, setting the text as the thing to be dragged.

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoDragDrop(this.label1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

If you drop the text in Firefox, it will load it the current tab. Look into Firefox configuration to see if you can have it open a new tab on drop.